# Multiple marker with latlngs value from database

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to input my `latlngs` value into `locations` something like:

```
var locations = [
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507]       
['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

This is my php codes:

```
$result = $conn->query("select address, lat, lang from user where phoneno = '" . $phoneno. "'");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"address":'  . $rs["address"] . ',';
$outp .= '"lat":"' . $rs["lat"] . '",';
$outp .= '"lang":"'   . $rs["lang"]        . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";
```

And this is the value output in url:

```
[{"address":Tampines Street 86,
  Singapore,"lat":"1.3498584","lang":"103.9273744"}]
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your question

Comment: Have a look @json_encode
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @Nitesh basically i wan to call the output from my php into my html as the values in var locations

Comment: @AlNoman Okay thanks for commenting! I'll have a look and update you on the results :)

Comment: @AlNoman I got my output to be like ["Tampines Street 86, Singapore",1.3497658,103.9274115]. Now how do I call it out in my html as the value for locations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get these values from your php and populate within HTML. [Here is an sample.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119387/json-to-html-table-in-php-javascript)

Comment: I cant seem to get it to work. It needs to be in a loop too